# Highcharts (column, candlestick) show mouseover tooltip anywhere on chart similar to line or area

Tags: javascript, charts, mouseover, highcharts

I'm currently working on chart similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/) using highcharts

From what I have observed, `column` and `candlestick` chart will only trigger `mouseover` when I hover on the box itself, whereas `line` or `area` chart will have them anywhere on the chart like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/)

So I've tried some configurations to try make `column` and `candlestick` to behave the same way as `line` or `area`, but haven't successful yet.

Ultimately, [this is the behaviour I want to achieve](https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/FB?ltr=1#symbol=FB;range=1d).

Would it be possible to change the `mouseover` behaviour of those charts to be the same as the line chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug which appeared in 5.0.8 version. You can see the closed ticket on github [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6456) which means that the fix will be included in the next release.

Until the release, you can use 5.0.7 version which works as you expect.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/5.0.7/highstock.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q947fsa2/1/

Comment: Thank you so much @morganfree, didn't know it was a bug. I ended up using the workaround instead downgrading version from the post answers